# Single word for the quality of being waterproof — "waterproofness", "waterproofity", something else?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

If someone is *happy*, I can refer to that state as that person's *happiness*.

If a watch is *waterproof*, do I refer to the watch's *waterproofness*, *waterproofity*, or what?

TFD has an entry that fits for [*happy*](http://tfd.com/happy), but not for [*waterproof*](http://tfd.com/waterproof).

I realize *resistance* is related ("I have a water resistant watch."), but I am curious if there is a word based on *waterproof* specifically.

In other words, is there a noun form of the adjective *waterproof*?

Comment: Interesting. "Impermeability" has little to do with the words water and proof!

Comment: [*Waterproofness*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waterproofness): "the property of being waterproof".

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA I've never used, nor do I believe I've ever heard that usage before today...

Comment: It seems that when manufacturers need to measure waterproofness they use they phrase ["waterproof rating"](http://www.google.com/#q=%22waterproof+rating%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=QGUtUK2OD-PV0QHW9oHQAQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=cd0820781f4eef2e&biw=1262&bih=559) instead of "waterproofness".

Comment: FWIW, "waterproofness" gets 34 instances in COCA. http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=17675710

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Waterproofness](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waterproof)* as a noun does indeed exist.

Comment: That sounds so wrong to me, but it looks like that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Despite a comment to the contrary, *[impermeable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impermeable)* has a sense meaning waterproof:   “not allowing passage, especially of liquids; waterproof”.  Also consider *[hydrophobic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hydrophobic)*, in its sense “lacking an affinity for water; unable to absorb, or be wetted by water”; and at a bit more of a stretch, *[insoluble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insoluble)*.

For a noun sort of word, besides previously-mentioned *waterproofness* consider *[hermeticity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hermeticity)*, "the condition of being hermetic (airtight)".  While hermetic refers to air-tightness or gas-tightness, it is sometimes used to describe diving chambers, which are both air-tight and water-tight, and also is used to describe underwater assemblies.  For a watch, either of *hermetically sealed* or *water-tight* might do.

Comment: I can certainly see uses of *impermeable* dealing with non-aquatic situations. However, I can't quickly come up with the same context for using *waterproof*. (*The army's defense was impermeable.*)

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, *waterproofness* does exist.  The OED lists a 1943 citation:

> *They offer advantages over certain other cellulose thermo-plastic adhesives by reason of their great toughness, waterproofness and heat sealing properties*.

along with another quote from the late 1970s that also references research from that same era:

> *The old style boot greases were developed during World War II for government use. Waterproofness of combat boots was the main objective.*

Interestingly enough, even though the OED had an entry for *waterproofness*, there was no entry for *soundproofness, fireproofness,* or *bulletproofness*.  That means, I suppose, I can talk about the waterproofness of my watch, but I'll need to find some other way to describe the the fireproofness of my pajamas, the soundproofness of my recording studio, and the bulletproofness of my limosine's windows.  *[Weatherproofness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=weatherproofness&ls=a)*, on the other hand, *is* listed as a word.